# Swift: Make control buttons not move with camera

Tags: ios, swift

I'm building a platform game, and I made the camera follow the player when he walks:

```
let cam = SKCameraNode()

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    self.camera = cam
    ...
}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */

    cam.position = Player.player.position
    ...
```

But, when the camera moves, the control buttons move as well
[image]

What should I do to keep the control buttons static?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See this note in the [`SKCameraNode` docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKCameraNode/index.html):

> A camera’s descendants are always rendered relative to the camera node’s origin and without applying the camera’s scaling or rotation to them. For example, if your game wants to display scores or other data floating above the gameplay, the nodes that render these elements should be descendants of the current camera node.

If you want HUD elements that stay fixed relative to the screen even as the camera moves/scales/rotates, make them child nodes of the camera.

By the way, you don't need to change the camera's position on every `update()`. Instead, just *constrain* the camera's position to match that of the player:

```
let constraint = SKConstraint.distance(SKRange(constantValue: 0), toNode: player)
camera.constraints = [ constraint ]
```

Then, SpriteKit will automatically keep the camera centered on the player without any per-frame work from you. You can even add more than one constraint — say, to follow the player but keep the camera from getting too close to the edge of the world (and showing empty space).

Comment: adding the constraint didn't work... and when I add the buttons as child, they disappear

Comment: nvm, I just forgot to add the camera child... btw, is there anyway to make this constraint follow only horizontally?

Comment: Let me guess: your player can jump, and you don't want the camera to jump with him? 1) The `SKRange` you pass to a constraint can have some slack in it. 2) Combine position constraints with the `referenceNode` property to constrain a position relative to some node. 3) You can have multiple constraints. Take those points and experiment a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Add the buttons as child to the camera, like `cam.addchild(yourButton)`

Answer (score 0):

From rickster's answer I made these constraints where the camera only moves horizontally, even if the player jumps. The order in which they are added is important. In case somebody else find them useful:

**Swift 4.2**

```
let camera = SKCameraNode()
scene.addChild(camera)
camera.constraints = [SKConstraint.distance(SKRange(upperLimit: 200), to: player),
                      SKConstraint.positionY(SKRange(constantValue: 0))]
```